# .NET Core Identity and IdentityServer4 in one project

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am creating Web Api with .Net Core. My project contains three solutions: Web API, Authentication server and Ocelot Gateway. I want to know how to configure my project to work with .NET Core Identity and IdentityServer4.

I used this documentation to generate token:

[Building API Gateway Using Ocelot In ASP.NET Core - Configuration (Consul)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-api-gateway-using-ocelot-in-asp-net-core-configuration-consul/)

Comment: Documetation : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-api-gateway-using-ocelot-in-asp-net-core-configuration-consul/

Comment: You have to build host application (or host inside) the IdentityServer4 instance (in general). Take a look on the IdentityServer4 samples. The [simple one is here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src).

Comment: As oleksa already said there are some good samples available. There also is [one for AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity).